# EmberJS, How to NOT render the parent View

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I have this `router`:

```
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('battles', function(){
    this.route('battle', { path: ':id' }, function(){
      this.route('combats', function() {
        this.route('new');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And these `templates`:

```
  // app/templates/battles.hbs
  {{#each model as |battle|}}
    {{battle.name}}
  {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}

  // app/templates/battles/battle/combats.hbs
  {{#each model as |combat|}}
    {{combat.date}}
  {{/each}}

  // app/templates/battles/battle/combats/new.hbs
  {{input type="text" value=date}}
  <button {{action "createCombat"}}>Create Combat</button>
```

So This is what is rendered for each `route`

```
  route: /battles
  -> app/templates/battles.hbs

  route: /battles/B2/combats
  -> app/templates/battles.hbs
  -> app/templates/battles/battle/combats.hbs

  route: /battles/B2/combats/new
  -> app/templates/battles.hbs
  -> app/templates/battles/battle/combats.hbs
```

So for the route `/battles/B2/combats/new` the template `app/templates/battles/battle/combats/new.hbs` is not rendered. This has a quick fix:

```
  // app/templates/battles/battle/combats.hbs
  {{#each model as |combat|}}
    {{combat.date}}
  {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}
```

But then the route renders this:

```
  route: /battles/B2/combats/new
  -> app/templates/battles.hbs
  -> app/templates/battles/battle/combats.hbs
  -> app/templates/battles/battle/combats/new.hbs
```

And I don't want the list of *combats* to be rendered when I'm rendering the `combat/new` form. I would like this:

```
  route: /battles/B2/combats/new
  -> app/templates/battles.hbs
  -> app/templates/battles/battle/combats/new.hbs
```

How I can create this setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the combats view to be rendered when displaying the 'new' view, you should place them on the same level and not the 'new' route beneath the 'combats' route. The super route is always called for a child route. Alternatively you could set a bool in your combats controller from the 'new' route. This is not very clean though.